# Android app error No view found for id(..) for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, view

I'm using a tabbed activity with 2 fragments. These 2 work just fine but I'm trying to create a button in the first fragment that will open up another fragment with a WebView. I'm getting no view found and i don't know how can fix it.
Here is the first fragment:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class Frag1 extends Fragment{
    private Button button;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment, container, false);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Frag3 frag3 = new Frag3();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.webid, frag3, "Web").commit();

            }
        });
        return view;
}
```

Here is the layout for the first fragment: tab1_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/tab1"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/webpage" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the fragment with the webview:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Frag3 extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Web";
    private WebView webView;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_fragment, container, false);
        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
        return view;
    }
}
```

And here is the layout for it: web_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webid"
    >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Everytime I press the button it will crash the app except for when i replace R.id.webid to R.id.tab1 which will show just the button or R.id.test2(which is the id for the activity_main layout) which will show an empty screen.
Any help will be appreciated!

Edit~ here is the Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 10381
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800d1 (com.example.myapplication:id/webid) for fragment Frag3{8ca7c59 #0 id=0x7f0800d1 Web}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1454)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post your LogCat. It would help everyone a lot if you gave more details on the crash.

Comment: The `R.id` you pass in the `replace()` call is the ID for the `ViewGroup` that the `Fragment` will be placed into, not one in the `Fragment`'s own layout. Where exactly do you want this new `Fragment` to be placed? Is it supposed to be just another tab page? Or do you want it inside one of the existing pages? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, it's gotta go somewhere. More specifically, its `View` has to go somewhere. Where do you want that `<RelativeLayout>` with the `<WebView>` to end up? If you don't want it stuck into your existing layout, maybe you're looking for a `DialogFragment` instead? Or maybe a separate `Activity`?

Comment: No, i want to be in a separated layout from the others, but if i want it inside one of the existing pages how should i do it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but if you want it added inside `Frag1`, you would use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`, and `R.id.tab1` instead of `R.id.webid`. That will add `Frag3`'s `<RelativeLayout>` inside of `Frag1`'s `<RelativeLayout>`, though, so without any additional layout rules, it'll end up overlapping the `<Button>` that's there initially.